# How/why does git rebase avoid a merge commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

The `git rebase` command uses a merge under the hood, so I am wondering how/why a `git rebase` avoids a merge commit whereas git merge usually creates a new commit if there is a diff between branches.

Comment: Rebase is not a merge. Git changes the base of branch and reapplies the commits changing the history in the process. A merge commits has two parent commits, a rebase re-orders the commits and is thereby flat.

Comment: @k0pernikus - `rebase` is not a `git merge`, nor is it a merge as done by server-based source-control, but it is a merge in the *english* sense of the word, yes?  And, for example, it can result in conflicts that have to be resolved with a `merge tool`.  That's my understanding, although I haven't run into the conflict situation yet myself.

Comment: @zzxyz: You are correct, and the way `git rebase` works is just by doing a series of merges and selecting the merge base in a particular way.

Answer (score 10):

`rebase` is not a merge like merging a branch. Instead, `rebase` is a series of `git cherry-pick`s. A cherry pick takes a commit and copies it as if it were written on top of some other commit. It's like if you took the diff of a commit and applied it somewhere else.

Consider a repository like this. A, B, C, etc... represent commit IDs.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F - G [feature]
```

If `master` needs `E`, maybe it's a critical bug fix, but not the rest of `feature`, it can `git cherry-pick E`. Git will do a merge between D and E with C as the origin resulting in E1. This is why you might get merge conflicts during a rebase. But unlike a normal merge, E1 will only have one parent.

```
A - B - C - D - E1 [master]
         \
          E - F - G [feature]
```

A rebase is like if did this for all your commits. And instead of being on top of `master` it moves `feature`. Here's what `git rebase master` looks like, step by step.

Again, consider your repository.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F - G [feature]
```

First, as before, it does a `cherry-pick` on E and puts it on top of `master`. But instead of moving `master`, it creates a new branch with no label.

```
              E1
             /
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F - G [feature]
```

Then it cherry-picks F and puts it on top of E1.

```
              E1 - F1
             /
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F - G [feature]
```

Then it cherry picks G and puts it on F1 as G1.

```
              E1 - F1 - G1
             /
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F - G [feature]
```

With the cherry-picking complete it moves the `feature` branch label to G1.

```
              E1 - F1 - G1 [feature]
             /
A - B - C - D [master]
         \
          E - F - G
```

And yes, the old commits are still there. If nothing references them, like a tag or another branch, they will be garbage collected in a few weeks. Meanwhile you can still access them with `git reflog`. See the [*Maintenance and Data Recovery* chapter of Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery) for more.

Comment: I'll just complement the answer by explaining that on each 'commits on top of X' a conflict can happen and it will require a conflict resolution. Also, recommend 'git help rebase' as a primary source of documentation to understand the rebase command.

Comment: The process of moving commits this way is in fact a merge, the git rebase documentation even uses the term “merge”. A rebase is little more than a sequence of merges, one for each commit, with the links to the parent erased.

Comment: @DietrichEpp While I can see how one can call applying a patch a  "merge", it's rather different conceptually from a branch merge. Saying that rebase does a series of merges is confusing. Git probably uses its merge machinery internally and that has leaked into its documentation.

Comment: If it's not a merge, then why can you specify a merge strategy? How is it possible to get merge conflicts on something that is not a merge? This is true for `git rebase`.

Comment: It is absolutely not correct that `git rebase` turns your commits into a series of patches, it does not work that way at all and if you think about it that way you will be surprised by the way `git rebase` works. What `git rebase` does, and `git cherry-pick`, is do a three-way merge. The fact that it works this way is not an internal detail that can be glossed over, it's essential to the way `git rebase` works and if you try to replicate the behavior of `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick` by applying a sequence of patches you will run into problems.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The essential thing, conceptually, is a rebase re-applies your commits as a series of patches. It's rather distinct from a branch merge. Mechanically Git uses the merge machinery to apply the patches. That's handy to know, for the reasons you mentioned, but it doesn't make a rebase a merge. That's like saying a Sherman tank is an aircraft because it uses an aircraft engine. High level concept: rebase reapplies your changes as a series of patches. Implementation detail: those patches are applied using merge machinery.

Comment: @Schwern: We seem to disagree about what the essential thing is. `git rebase` does not in fact apply your commits as a series of patches, because this would be error-prone and fragile, it would not get the same results. It performs a sequence of three-way merges. Afterwards, you can reconstruct a sequence of patches, but these patches only exist after the rebase finishes. If you think if it as a sequence of three way merges, you can have a simpler mental model without a separate, inaccurate high-level view.

Comment: Now, there *are* in fact other version control systems which support the same functionality but use a sequence of patches... such as Darcs. In Darcs, doing this requires computing patch commutations.

Comment: @DietrichEpp What do you think of it now?

Answer (score 3):

I like to split the concept of *merging*, in Git, into two parts:

- The verb *to merge* means *to combine changes*.  Many commands use this.
- The noun *a merge*, derived from the adjective form *merge commit* where the adjective "merge" modifies the noun "commit", means *a commit with two or more parents*.  Only `git merge` builds such commits (well, `git merge` or things that run `git merge`, including `git pull`).

What this means is that `git rebase` uses the verb form, the *to merge* operation, which generally occurs via repeated `git cherry-pick`.<sup>1</sup>  Git cherry-picks a commit by performing a merge with the commit's parent<sup>2</sup> as the merge base, the commit itself as the "other" commit, and the current `HEAD` commit playing its normal role.  [zzxyz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280464/how-why-does-git-rebase-avoid-a-merge-commit#comment91509479_52280464) is thus correct: each cherry-pick operation can result in merge conflicts, which a human must resolve.

The result of each cherry-pick operation is a copy of each commit, as [Schwern noted in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281044/1256452).  After copying the commits of interest, Git moves the branch name so that it points to the final copied commit—the tip of the new branch in its new position in the commit graph.  The original commits remain for at least a little while due to `ORIG_HEAD`—which `rebase` sets before moving the branch name—and due to various reflogs (for `HEAD` itself and/or for the branch name that `git rebase` just changed).

The last thing worth noting here is this phrase *the commits of interest* in the preceding paragraph.  When rebase lays out the commits it will copy, it *deliberately discards merges* by default.  There are arguments to be made on either side of this ("keep merges" vs "discard merges", that is), but that's what Git does today.  So after rebasing, the copies never include any merge commits, even if the *process* of copying commits involves the *to merge* verb.

---

<sup>1</sup>An interactive `git rebase -i`, or a `git rebase` run with `-m` or `-s strategy`, really uses `git cherry-pick`.  A non-interactive rebase without `-m` or `-s` uses `git format-patch` and `git am -3`, which is technically inferior in several ways, but is backwards compatible with ancient Git 1.5.

<sup>2</sup>This is what makes cherry-picking a merge difficult: a merge—a merge commit, which by definition is a commit with two or more parents—does not have *a* parent, it has *two or more* parents.  The `git cherry-pick` command will let you pick it anyway, but to do so, you must specify *which* parent the command should treat as the merge base during the merge-as-a-verb process.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it this way: `git rebase` takes the new commits from your branch and set them aside, then rewinds your branch to match the updated original one, then finally adds your commits on top of the result; `git merge` simply creates a new (merge) commit with the difference between the branches. Note that in the case of rebasing all the commits that were not present on the original branch will change their hashes, so you're gonna have to force push the new branch (which is not always easy if there are multiple people collaborating on the same branch). Rebasing, however, lets you avoid merge commits and keep cleaner history.

Comment: Force push is not required if only the local branch changes. E.g. pulling changes through `git pull` vs `git pull --rebase`.

Comment: Force push also never seems to be required when merging a remote with a local.  I assume the force push use case must involve using rebase to merge explicitly created branches? (which I personally would never do...well, not if they made it to the remote anyway)

Comment: Well, obviously you don’t need to force push if the branch only exists locally. The note was addressing the case when you’re bringing up to date a branch that was previously pushed to origin.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people have answered *how* `rebase` avoids a merge commit, but I think *why* is a bit interesting.  There are tons of things you can do with it, so this is just my opinion on the most important one.  (Others with different workflows will naturally disagree :)

In a centralized repository system, such as `svn` or `perforce`, commits are done straight to the server.  So if Bob and Jim are both working on their local copies of the main branch...they are both working on the main branch.  End of story.  After Bob and Jim do their commits, we see them, in order...in one branch.

One of the very few *potential* drawbacks to `git` is that a remote repository is *effectively* an implicit branch.  It behaves like one, it shows up in git log like one, etc.  So if Bob and Jim both make changes to their local copy, the last one to push has to pull...and do a merge from the remote.  And that shows up as if Bob and Jim had both been working on their own branches.  Sometimes this behavior is perfect.  Sometimes it is undesirable.

`git pull --rebase`/`git fetch;git rebase` is how you can tell `git` "I know *you* consider this a branch, but I don't.  I just want to do my commit on top of the last one like a normal person and have what I consider an *accurate* branch history." I personally don't care much about *clean*.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct that a rebase is basically a merge under the hood. In fact, you can make your own rebase command using the merge command, and all you need to do is modify some commit metadata afterwards.

Let’s say this is your history:

```
A - B - C (master)
 \
  D - E (dev)
```

If you want to rebase dev onto master, you can do it by first merging D and then E,

```
A - B - C - D'- E'
 \         /   /
  + - - - D - E
```

And then you modify the commits to remove the links from D and E,

```
A - B - C - D"- E" (master)
 \
  D - E (dev)
```

So you can see that git rebase is nothing more than some straightforward history manipulation (only changing metadata) on top of a merge. The reason you don’t see merge commits is simply a question of metadata—each commit has pointers to its parent commits, and if you delete all but one of the pointers, you erase a commit’s connection to those parents, turning a merge commit into a non-merge commit.

More complicated rebases can be done this way, too. Note that this is not how rebase actually works, it’s just a way that you can manually rebase commits without using the rebase or cherry-pick commands. The important part is that a merge commit is nothing more than a commit with two or more parents, and you can change any commit’s parents just by modifying the metadata.

Comment: This is not how `git-rebase` works. It does not do merges and then delete the merge commits. You can see this by doing a `git rebase -i`, stopping in the middle by doing an `edit`, and then looking at the repository with `git log --graph --decorate --all`. There will be no intermittent merge commits. Instead, a rebase is better described as a series of cherry-picks.

Comment: I'm glad we both agree that this is not how `git-rebase` works. However, a cherry pick is nothing more than a type of merge. It just performs the merge with a different base, and doesn't create a merge commit. Whether a merge commit is created is different from whether or not a merge actually happened, with both `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` you *are* actually merging, that's what these commands do, they simply don't produce merge commits.

Comment: @Schwern: On a pedagogical note, I think it's important to describe all of these operations as merges, because otherwise people will be surprised when they find that there are merge conflicts. Think about it this way... if a rebase or a cherry pick is not a merge, why do they accept a merge strategy as an argument? Why can they have merge conflicts? The answer is that these are just special types of merges, with some extra bookkeeping.

Comment: I think this answer would work great if it instead demonstrated how cherry-pick works, with all the merge details, and then showed rebasing as a series of cherry-picks. That would eliminate the inaccuracy of showing rebase as a series of branch merges which are then undone at the end while still showing the merge machinery in action.

Comment: @Schwern: Fundamentally, a three-way merge is just an operation on three trees that produces a fourth, so the history does not affect the output in any way. So you can either construct a clean history as you go, or you can perform "dirty" merges and clean up the history afterwards, the result will be the same. The example is designed to be simple to illustrate the concept, I think people are smart enough to figure out that the implementation details are different.